# Draw activity Android

Tags: android

For an app i'm making, people need to be able to sign their signature on a white canvas, with a special tactile pen, or their finger. I haven't found a clear way of accomplishing this on the android developer website, or on random tutorials.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check this example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

api demo >> graphics >> finger paint
[finger paint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)